# Can't click on an element from menu that appears after hovering

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

So this is the element I'm trying to find

```
<a href="" class="deleteLinkItem" data-toggle="modal" data-id="k2"
data-target="delete" tableindex="-1">Delete</a>
```

It's in a menu that opens when hovering another element. I hover with Actions successfully but then I can't catch this one. I tried with XPath, with class...No solution. Does anyone have any idea what to do now?

Comment: Please share code live for Hover and error you are getting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem could be that the library you are using is changing the classes (adding and removing classes) of your element.

There is two ways to address this issue:

The first solution is to add an id to your element and use such with the click event.

The second solution is to figure out, with the tools provided in your browser, which are the classes that are being added and removed by the library that controls your element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, I know Java Binding I think it wouldn't be too difficult to convert this code to C#

After hovering the menu, write this code

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10L).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Delete"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this XPATH `//a[text()='Delete']`

Comment: He is hovering, so Explicit wait is essential.

Comment: yes i know i suggested him another way to find the element but he has make an explicit wait like your answer but with xpath `new WebDriverWait(driver,10L).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Delete']"))).click();`

Comment: Okay, that's great!